# What components can you use to create AIR apps?

Tags: flash, air, components, flashdevelop, apache-flex

I'm creating AIR apps in FlashDevelop using the free Flex SDK.

Are there any AS3 components that I can use to speeden up the development process??

For example:

- List with renaming
- Tree with dragging items, renaming

I searched Google lots, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever considered [using the flex components](http://filt3r.free.fr/index.php/2007/08/11/28-using-flex-3-component-without-mxml-only-as3) or even coding in MXML?

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd: not sure I understand. The example is for AS3, no? Basically, you could also create an AIR flex project (maybe you need the newest FD for the project template to be included), and then just add your Main class to the Application and continue with pure AS3 from there.